# PHP: How to serve JPG files (from a webcam) as a stream or movie?

Tags: javascript, php, mjpeg, timelapse, jsmovie

I have a set of images with filenames in the format `webcam-<timestamp>.jpg` located in a folder on the webserver. I want to serve them as a kind of timelapse slideshow to the client.

Is there a way to create a movie stream on-the-fly from these images (maybe as mjpeg) and serve this stream to a browser?

If not, is there way in PHP to take these files and convert them to a mjpeg file (or other movie format) and let the browser download/stream this file?

Do you have another idea how to create a kind of slideshow for webcam pictures like [this](http://www.bergfex.com/jauerling/webcams/c5631/) (maybe using JS/AJAX)? Is there a project out there, which I can use (I am a really bad js scripter, so that would be a great help)?

In the past I used the [jsmovie](https://github.com/konsultaner/jsMovie) project, but jsmovie loads all pictures into the memory of the browser which can get quite a huge amount of RAM used on the client).

Any help or thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Just make a js based loop that downloads the files and shows them in turn.

Comment: i would just fetch the static images client side and render them in canvas. i would avoid trying to mux mp4s on the fly.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! As mentioned, I am not very good in JS and I think there must be projects out there which exactly do that. Can you pinpoint me to some of them? The only one I found, was jsmovie, which is not developed anymore and also loads all images into the memory, which makes it unusable for phones and tablets.